# I am able to hit a SOAP web service from eclipse, but not from a jar file

Tags: web-services, executable-jar

I have a webservice wsdl, i need to hit it and parse the response.
I am able to hit it from my IDE Eclipse, but when i make a runnable jar file it shows following error.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
```

We have already performed whitelisting related work at server end but still the problem remains the same.
Can anyone suggest anything ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After so many searching and implementations, I've found one line which solved it. Server `environment` was not supporting my `protocol`.

I added  below line it solved the problem

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was because the protocol at client side was not same as protocol used at server side. So to bypass it we can set property according to server side ans our request will be successful.